# Kaggle scatterplot showing a unique error

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using kaggle and today I received an error which I've never seen before.

```
library("tidyverse") #everything you need for data manipulation
library("ggplot2") #everything you need for visualization
remove.packages("ggmap") #stamen is migrating to stadia
install.packages("devtools") #cran install devtools
devtools::install_github("stadiamaps/ggmap") #stadia is used for stamen maps

stations <- read.csv("/.../Divvy_Stations_2017_Q3Q4.csv", na = "")
ggplot() + 
geom_point(data = stations, mapping = aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, 
        size = dpcapacity))
```

The error is:

```
Warning message in draw_axis(break_positions = guide$key[[aesthetic]], break_labels = guide$key$.label, :

“internal error -3 in R_decompress1”

 ERROR while rich displaying an object: Error in draw_axis(break_positions = 
 guide$key[[aesthetic]], break_labels = guide$key$.label, : lazy-load database 
 '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/gtable/R/gtable.rdb' is corrupt
```

Is it because of devtools?